# How to get `expr match` to extract colon-delimited key-value pair?

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

Given: `myvar="present-value: 1"`, I'd expect `expr match "$myvar" '\([0-9]\)'` to output `1`. However, instead it outputs blank and exits with a non-zero status code indicating no match.

How can I get it to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
myvar="present value: 4"
expr match "$myvar" '.*\([0-9]\)'
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: That is interesting. On regex101.com I'm able to match just the number using the range [0-9] or the actual number itself 1. But expr seems to refuse to work that way. So basicly i have to match the whole thing and use () to specify what to print. Weird that we cant match the number directly.

Answer (score 2):

Per the `exper` man page, `match` is for an `anchored pattern match of REGEXP in STRING`.  The REGEX is anchored to both ends of STRING, so it can't just match a substring.